# Display the fetched data from mongoDB database with mongoose to next.js frontend with several api endpoints

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js, endpoint, mongodb-compass

I want to fetch the following sample data using an API and display it on the frontend in table format. I want to be able to filter the data based on certain conditions and display it according to the user's choice.

I am using Next.js with Node.js and Express.js.

Dependencies:

```json
"body-parser": "^1.20.2",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^16.0.3",
"eslint": "8.39.0",
"eslint-config-next": "13.3.1",
"express": "^4.18.2",
"mongoose": "^7.0.4",
"next": "13.3.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0"
```

pages/index.js:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import Table from "@/components/table/table";
import styles from "@/styles/Home.module.css";

export default function UserTable() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);

  const handleApiChange = async (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    // console.log({ value });
    try {
      const res = await fetch(value);
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log({ data });
      setUserData(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  console.log({ userData });

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <h1 className={styles.heading}>User Data</h1>
      <select onChange={handleApiChange} className={styles.menu}>
        <option value="">--Select an API--</option>
        <option value="/api/users/bmw_mercedes_income_less_5">
          BMW/Mercedes with income less than $5
        </option>
        <option value="/api/users/male_phone_price_gt_10000">
          Male users with phone price greater than $10,000
        </option>
        <option value="/api/users/bmw_mercedes_audi_email_no_digit">
          BMW/Mercedes/Audi with email that does not contain digits
        </option>
      </select>
      {!!userData.length && <Table userData={userData} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

pages/api/index.js

```js
//jshint esversion:6

import express from "express";
// import { json } from "body-parser";
// import cors from "cors";
import sampleData from "@/data/stats.json";
require("dotenv").config(); // for security purpose

const app = express();
const port = 5500;

// app.use(cors());
// app.use(json());

// use .env file for storing these values to avoid exposing it
const usernameMongoDB = process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME;
const passwordMongoDB = process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD;

// MongoDB connection and schema definition goes here
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(
  `mongodb+srv://${usernameMongoDB}:${passwordMongoDB}@cluster0.fnyielu.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
  { useNewUrlParser: true }
);

// Define schema for User object
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  // new mongoose.Schema
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
  phone: String,
  income: Number,
  car: {
    brand: String,
    model: String,
    year: Number,
  },
  gender: String,
  quote: String,
});

// Clear the users model before redefining it
delete mongoose.connection.models["users"];
const users = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema); // can also use _model(..)

// load sample data
sampleData.forEach(async (data) => {
  try {
    const userData = new users(data);
    const result = await userData.save();
    console.log("Data loaded successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occured while loading data");
  }
});

// condition: Users which have income lower than $5 USD and have a car of brand “BMW” or “Mercedes-Benz”
// Routes for fetching the required data
app.get("/api/users/bmw_mercedes_income_less_5", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let query = {
      $and: [
        { car: { $in: ["BMW", "Mercedes-Benz"] } }, // "car.brand"
        { income: { $lt: "5" } },
      ],
    };
    // we can also use: { $or: [ { car: "BMW", income: {$lt: "$5.00"} }, { car: "Mercedes-Benz", income: {$lt: "$5.00"} } ] }
    const results = await users.find(query);
    res.status(200).json(results);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});

// condition: Male Users which have phone price greater than 10,000.
app.get("/api/users/male_phone_price_gt_10000", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let query = {
      $and: [{ gender: "Male" }, { phone_price: { $gt: "10000" } }],
    };
    const results = await users.find(query);
    res.status(200).json(results);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});

// condition: Users which have a car of brand “BMW”, “Mercedes-Benz” or “Audi” and whose email does not include any digit.
app.get("/api/users/bmw_mercedes_audi_email_no_digit", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let query = {
      car: { $in: ["BMW", "Mercedes-Benz", "Audi"] },
      email: { $not: { $regex: "\\d" } },
    };
    const results = await users.find(query);
    res.status(200).json(results);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`API server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Data: (10k rows)

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Inglis",
    "last_name": "McMurty",
    "email": "imcmurty0@youku.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "income": "$1.36",
    "city": "Las Flores",
    "car": "Hummer",
    "quote": "optimize web-enabled relationships",
    "phone_price": "22236"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Hersh",
    "last_name": "Reynault",
    "email": "hreynault1@jimdo.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "income": "$0.36",
    "city": "Lianran",
    "car": "Mazda",
    "quote": "deploy revolutionary eyeballs",
    "phone_price": "56191"
  }
]
```

I have verified the queries using MongoDB Compass.
I have loaded the data into the `users` collection in the `test` database.

What I want to achieve:

1. I want to fetch JSON data properly from the MongoDB database. Currently, I am not getting the same result as `http://localhost:3000/api/users/bmw_mercedes_income_less_5` with Postman.
2. I want the userData array to be properly filled instead of returning an empty array as it currently does.
3. Is there a need for getServerStaticProps since we are only fetching the data based on choice? We can also fetch all the data using Axios. Nonetheless, I want to know what is wrong here.
4. I want a query in which email includes his/her last name?

I have tried fetching the data using different endpoint in api sub-directory of pages directory.

I have written the code, and getting `{ userData: [] }` which is technically wrong, and doesn't make sense.

Console error:

```
p://localhost:3000/api/users/bmw_mercedes_income_less_5 404 (Not Found)
handleApiChange @ index.js:13
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
eval @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
handleMouseUp_ @ unknown
client.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
```